# ruby WSDL error

Tags: ruby, soap, wsdl

I'm banging my head against the wall on this error.  After generating my classes out with wsdl2ruby, when I go to post a sale against the webservice I get the following error.

> SOAP::FaultError:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid
>   element in
>   com.marquis.eomis.canteeninventoryandsales.resource.canteenSale.CanteenSaleContent
>   - user

The user element is a valid element required by the CanteenSaleType.  Is the WSDL that was generated faulty????

Answer (score 0):

Is the WSDL faulty? - probably not. wsdl2ruby.rb is fairly picky about how you pass arguments. Can you post the relevant piece of the WSDL and the relevant pieces of the generated code?

Comment: directly from the WSDL or a PP of the object i'm passing in ??

Comment: The WSDL definition of the method you're calling, the generated code that corresponds to that method (i.e., the output of wsdl2ruby), and the code you're using to construct the parameters and call the method would all be helpful.